# amCharts4: Collapsed charts becoming blank after related interactivity

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

I have six charts in a page, three gauges and three XY charts.
The 3 gauge charts are always visible, while the XY charts are collapsed by default.

On page load, all the charts are correctly drawn, whether they are collapsed or not. But if I refresh all charts, for instance after changing a datepicker value, all the collapsed charts become white.

How can I avoid this? Is there a command to invalidate chart size, or just redraw it when div is resized?

EDIT:

I was able to reproduce a similar behaviour with tabs: on page load all the tabs are correctly shown, but if I click a refresh button to redraw charts, the tabs not currently visible become blank.

You can check here: https://jsfiddle.net/giulia_pinnisi/cqoz5vbg/13/

```
draw_chart("chart1", data1);
draw_chart("chart2", data2);
draw_chart("chart3", data3);

$('#refresh_button').click(function() {
  draw_chart("chart1", data1);
  draw_chart("chart2", data2);
  draw_chart("chart3", data3);
});
```

Thank you very much

Giulia

Comment: Can you post your code? Is the datepicker your own creation?

Comment: No, it's a date range picker: http://www.daterangepicker.com/. The code is a little bit long and I won't paste it here, anyway the steps are: on datepicker selection change, call a function date_changed() which calls a list of function, like loadPerformanceRatio(..) who makes an ajax call to get the values to draw on my charts.

Comment: @Giuly - Code would *really* help. SO recommends providing an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); a simplified version of your setup that reproduces would help get a sense of how you're updating/drawing everything.

Comment: I just added an example of a different but similar situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [dispose](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/xychart/#dispose_method) the chart if you want to re-instantiate it.

```
chart.dispose();
```

Check the updated example: https://jsfiddle.net/hosfrcd8/

Comment: I discovered that I was trying to create a new chart in the same container over existing one.

That is not right way to do it. The old SVG is overwritten, but all the variables, event handlers, helper elements remain, and quite possible causing all kinds of issues.

As you said, to overwrite a chart I have to call dispose() on its object first.

Better yet, if someone needs to just update data of the charts, you can reuse same objects, and just set their data property.